# Is there a generic way to execute different python files, depending on sys.args?

Tags: python

I would like to create a python file that can be run from the terminal - this file will be in charge of running various other python files depending on the functionality required along with their required arguments, respectively. For example, this is the main file:

```
import sys
from midi_to_audio import arguments, run


files = ["midi_to_audio.py"]


def main(file, args):

    if file == "midi_to_audio.py":

        if len(args) != arguments:
            print("Incorrect argument length")
        else:
            run("test","t")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    sys.argv.pop(0)
    file = sys.argv[0]
    sys.argv.pop(0)

    if file not in files:
        print("File does not exist")

    else:
        main(file, sys.argv)
```

And this is the first file used in the example (midi_to_audio.py):

```
arguments = 2


def run(file, output_file):
    print("Ran this method")
```

So depending on which file I've specified when running the cmd via the terminal, it will go into a different file and call its run method. If the arguments are not as required in each file, it will not run

For example: `>python main.py midi_to_audio.py file_name_here output_name_here`

My problem is that, as I add more files with their own "arguments" and "run" functions, I wonder if python is going to get confused with which arguments or which run function to execute. Is there a more safer/generic way of doing this?

Also, is there a way of getting the names of the python files depending on which files I've imported? Because for now I have to import the file and manually add their file name to the files list in main.py

Comment: "if python is going to get confused with which arguments or which run function to execute." No, Python will not get confused, since it just runs the code you tell it to.

Comment: @AKX, if I have multiple files with their own function named "run". Then in the main file, I will have to import run from each file. And so when I call "run" in the main, how will it know to use run from one file, rather than the other?

Comment: I could just rename each run function like run_file1(args), or run_file2(args), but I just want something generic so that it's very concise in main.py

Comment: just use a command line interface library like Click or Typer

Comment: @TomMcLean Using those libraries doesn't help with OP's original problem which is dispatching to different modules dynamically.

Comment: @AKX I'm saying thats a bad way to do it, just be explicit in what you can do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your runner could look like this, to load a module by name and check it has `run`, and check the arguments given on the command line, and finally dispatch to the module's `run` function.

```
import sys
import importlib


def main():
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    if len(args) < 1:
        raise Exception("No module name given")
    module_name = args.pop(0).removesuffix(".py")  # grab the first argument and remove the .py suffix
    module = importlib.import_module(module_name)  # import a module by name
    if not hasattr(module, 'run'):   # check if the module has a run function
        raise Exception(f"Module {module_name} does not have a run function")
    arg_count = getattr(module, 'arguments', 0)  # get the number of arguments the module needs
    if len(args) != arg_count:
        raise Exception(f"Module {module_name} requires {arg_count} arguments, got {len(args)}")
    module.run(*args)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This works with the `midi_to_audio.py` module in your post.

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked :) I also added to this answer: to check if the module does in fact exist. Thanks for your help!